# What is the relationship between Reconstitution Factories and Repositories in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

According to Evans, in DDD we have two types of Factories, one type for object creation and other type for reconstituting stored objects.

a) While `Creation factories` can exist as `Standalone Factory objects` or as `Factory methods` defined on the root of the Aggregates, should `Reconstitution Factories` exist only as `Standalone Factory objects`?

b) I assume `Reconstitution Factories` should only be used/called by repositories, which will delegate object creation to them?

c) Should `Reconstitution Factories` be defined within  a `domain layer`, even though they will only be used by repositories?

**UPDATE:**

My questions are purely theoretical in nature, since I only started learning DDD

> I assume that your objects are persisted in a RDBMS not in an oo db .

Yes, they are persisted into relational DB

> I see them as simple data transition from the DB to a domain object
>   (get the field from result set and put it in the object, without any
>   validation or other logic)

a) If I understand you correctly, you're saying that even if a creation of particular object is complex enough to use a `creation factory` for it, reconstitution of that same object in most cases isn't as complex as its creation and thus no need for `reconstitution factory`?

b) And your reasoning why reconstitution is less complex than creation is based on the assumption that objects stored in DB are already in valid state?

> Data mapping objects should be in a different layer. The data mapping
>   layer should be unknown to the domain

I agree

c)

> I consider "reconstitution factories" as data mappers and they should
>   reside outside the domain.

But according to Evans, factories ( I'm assuming he means both creation and reconstituition factories ) are dealing with domain concepts ( ie they must know something about the internal structure of an entity or Aggregate they are trying to create/reconsititute ) and as such are part of the domain ( even though they don't represent any domain concepts ), while data mappers aren't part of the domain and also don't have any knowledge of object's internal structure?!

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that your objects are persisted in a RDBMS not in an oo db .

Reconstitution of already persisted objects, that should always be in a valid state, is not complex. I see them as simple data transition from the DB to a domain object (get the field from result set and put it in the object, without any validation or other logic) . For simplicity, in my opinion, methods inside the repositories that rebuild an object based on a result set are enough to keep the repository highly cohesive.

If you really want to go the way of reconstitution factories (and if your domain is complex enough to need such objects), maybe you need a proper ORM framework . Data mapping objects should be in a different layer. **The data mapping layer should be unknown to the domain.** From Martin Fowler's website : "[Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) also supports the objective of achieving a clean separation and one-way dependency between the domain and data [mapping layers](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)." , [link](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

**I consider "reconstitution factories" as [data mappers](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and they should reside outside the domain.**

Comment: I would answer the same.

Comment: a) yes that is true . And if you design your db to resamble your domain (1 table 1 object, but it's harder in rdbms but not impossible) it's even easyer to reconstitute the objects

Comment: b) Yes , i use creation factories to enforce a valid state for the newly created objects . The reconstitution factories won't need to redo this hard work . The hardest work of a reconstitution factory is to map the db data to domain objects .

Comment: @bckpwrld c) Reconstitution factories will have only a simplistic ideea of the domain objects . They only need to know that a domain object has some attributes and nothing more . They don;t need to know it's behaviour, only the attributes so they can map the data . Same as the application code , even the app code that is in the app layer can know about what attributes a domain object has . Creation factories need to know what is a valid state, and the repos acting as a bridge beetween domain and mapper , beign more tied to the domain (repos hold the persisted objects) lies in the domain .

Comment: View repositories as holders of domain object collections . They may use any data source pattern . If you inject DAL (mapper , a table gateway) into repositories it is clear that the repository will ultimately provide access for the persisted needed objects.

Comment: So if for whatever reasons some of objects stored in DB may not be in valid state, then you'd agree that in such cases reconstitution factories would not be data mappers, but in fact would be defined in the domain?

Comment: @bckpwrld Yes because you will have to check if the state is valid in that domain context . But you should never have invalid persisted domain objects . Why would you store in memory invalid objects ? Also if you change data management to OODB , data mapper would be useless . That's why you need a repository (another abstraction layer) tied to the domain and a DAL (mapper , active record , table gateway etc) tied to the data management system .

Comment: "Also if you change data management to OODB ... That's why you need a repository" Perhaps you've misunderstood my question? I know we need repositories in order to adhere to Persistence Ignorance rule. I was just curious whether in most cases reconstitution factories will only be called from within repository implementation ( repository implementation resides within infrastructure layer ) or are there cases where some domain code will also need to call reconstitution factories

Comment: Actually i keep repositories in the domain layer , inside a corespondent domain bounded context (a domain module that includes creation factories , aggregates, events etc) . DAL (and not the repositories) should be in the infrastructure layer . Yes reconstitution factories should be used only by repositories (when coupling them with the domain) .

Comment: You're saying you're also keeping repository implementations in the domain layer? Isn't that wrong? And thank you for your help

Comment: Well , i rarely use interfaces . I don't see why is it stricktly neccessary to hide the impementation from the domain (again i rarely use interfaces).